# Chrome при resize показывает неверные размеры

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, vue.js, angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При resize Chrome показывает неверные размеры, в то время как при наведении на элемент и в консоли верные

Comment: у меня не воспроизводится. Все цифры совпадают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было сбросить страницу на 100%.